# How to set multi-select field value using openForm in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, multi-select, xrm, picklist

I've created Multi-select option-set field (category) in Dynamics CRM on-premise for Contact and Projects. Now using button click I'm trying to set the value of multi-select field on Project. But each time I am coming across with Error:

> `Error converting value 920650008 to type System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.Int32]`.

Since the multi-select optionset field is global so there is no chance of specified values available or not.

Here is what I am trying previously:

```
var name = formContext.getAttribute(new.account_metada.CompanyName).getValue();
var entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "new_projects";
    entityFormOptions["openInNewWindow"] = true;
var formParameters["new_company"] = id; 
    formParameters["new_companyname"] = name;
    formParameters["new_category"]  = formContext.getAttribute("new_category").getValue()

    Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions, formParameters).then(
                function (success) {
                    console.log(success);
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

Please let me know how to can I set value of multi-select optionset using `Xrm.Navigation.openForm`

Comment: `var multiSelectOptionSet = formContext.getAttribute("new_category").getValue();`
Debug and check whether  `multiSelectOptionSet ` returns Array. If it does then `formParameters["new_category"]  = multiSelectOptionSet` This shall help. Also for testing you can pass hardcode array values of Multiselect to check if all works properly.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this personally and getting the same error result with the below snippet. Though [the syntax is right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/set-field-values-using-parameters-passed-form#example-use-xrmnavigationopenform-to-open-a-new-window) - Something could be wrong with the `Xrm.Navigation.openForm()` method or this could be expected behavior because of [unsupported Array datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/configure-form-accept-custom-querystring-parameters#edit-formxml).

```
var entityFormOptions = new Array();
entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "my_entity";
entityFormOptions["openInNewWindow"] = false;

var formParameters = new Array();
formParameters["new_multiselectpicklist"]  = formContext.getAttribute("new_multiselectpicklist").getValue();

Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions, formParameters).then(
                function (success) {
                    console.log(success);
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

Even a hard code assignment getting the same error:

```
formParameters["new_multiselectpicklist"]  = [962080001, 962080002];
```

---

**Edit**:

The above line should be like this to make it work.

```
formParameters["new_multiselectpicklist"]  = "[962080001, 962080002]";
```

---

I tried [this alternate option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/set-field-values-using-parameters-passed-form#example-set-the-value-for-multi-select-option-set-fields) using `extraqs` and it worked.

```
https://mycrmdev.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=my_entity&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=new_multiselectpicklist=[962080001, 962080002]
```

Comment: @MohsinA. Interesting, it failed when I hard coded the square brackets around it.

Answer (score 1):

I got fix the issue by replacing below source code line:

**Existing**

`formParameters["new_multiselectpicklist"]  = formContext.getAttribute("new_multiselectpicklist").getValue();`

**Updated**

`formParameters["new_multiselectpicklist"]  = "["+formContext.getAttribute("new_multiselectpicklist").getValue()+"]";`